# Recommendations for an exemplary presentation of statistics related to preclinical drug studies and cellular chemistry?

Tags: cell-biology, statistics

I am reading [Nature's recommendations for collecting and presenting statistics](http://www.nature.com/collections/qghhqm), but would like to also read a few exemplary articles with good charts and data presentation to learn what it looks like when done well. Would be grateful for recommendations -- thanks!